# Why does my Visual Studio 2019 IDE show gibberish for the Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2019, toolbox

I have the latest Visual Studio 2019 and my MFC project has now started to show the toolbox items in a weird way in the resource editor:

[image: IDE]

It also does this for new projects. The Dialog node in the toolbox is fine though.

Comment: Performing a "repair" resolved the issue.